# What does "normal people" mean, literally?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

> 1, What do ***normal*** people talk about? Well, ***normal*** people like to share experiences with each other.
>
> 2, Celebrities can live a luxurious life. ***Normal*** people can't afford that.
>
> 3, I can't cure your mental illness like a professional. I am just a ***normal*** person. You should go to a therapist.
>
> 4,   ***Normal*** people don't react that way.

Is *normal* the antonym of *abnormal* in these examples? Do these sentences mean that: those who don't like to share experiences are *abnormal*, celebrities are *abnormal*, therapists are *abnormal*, those who act that way are *abnormal*?

Or is this usage correct? Is there another word that can characterise people without parting them into normal and abnormal?

Comment: I'm curious to know if the term "normal" in the OP's native language has only one fixed definition? And if English is their first language, then the question is pretty biased and loaded; it probably belongs to Philosophy.SE.

Comment: To tell you if *normal* is the antonym of *abnormal* in the contexts provided, you have to define *abnormal*.

Comment: When looking at human characteristics, although some classifications are binary, most are graded: continuums. Then one has to define the 'normal' region (and often, before this, agree methods of measurement). So with non-binary situations (and even some binary ones), 'normal' is arbitrary, opinion-based.  And one has to beware of stigmatising: though 'Normal people have two eyes of the same colour' is clear, people blessed with heterochromia iridium will probably dislike the 'abnormal' implication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure using ***normal*** is an issue, many will not interpret it in the way you did. In the first sentence, I agree that the use of ***normal*** can be seen as somewhat ambiguous and problematic. In fact I don't see the point of the question and the answer.

In sentences 2 and 3, ***normal*** is not the antonym of ***abnormal***. It just means ***not having the particular characteristics that makes the other category stand out*** (respectively *celebrities* and *therapists*). Sentence 4 would need more context. But here I would see ***normal*** as meaning ***[most](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/most-the-most-mostly)***:

> ***Most*** people don't react that way.

Communication has become over sensitive nowadays, so if you want to avoid parting humanity into a good and bad category of people, you could use the adjective ***average*** which means:

> typical and usual:
>
> - The ***average*** person on the street is a lot better off than they were 40 years ago. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/average))

The more obvious antonym of ***average*** would be ***above average/atypical***. And you could argue that in certain aspects a celebrity is not your average person, as well as a specialised therapist.

Instead of *I am just a normal person*, I also thought of the American expression

> I am just a ***regular*** guy

but it has [connotations](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/regular) that your sentence does not.

Comment: I would say point 4 is saying something is wrong with the person

Comment: @WendyG It could be a compliment though! If a policeman adopts the child of a drug addict mother he found on the streets, you could say that about them with the intention of praise.

Comment: that is the missing context yeah.